# this on JavaScript module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

I wrote a script for binding the "smooth scroll" clicking on a button using the JavaScript Module Pattern.

Since is the first time I write code on module pattern, I need some help on the use of "this".

When I bind the "scroll" function to my "bindevents" function, I get an error saying that the "this", in the "scroll" function, is undefined.

How should i use "this" to select the button I click?

Here is the code:

```js
var s, SmoothScroll = {

  Selectors: {
    Link: $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])')
  },

  scroll: function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname && $(".classes .section").has(this).length == 0 ) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  },

  bindEvents: function() { 
    s.Link.click(function() {
      SmoothScroll.scroll();
    });
  },

  init: function(){
    s = this.Selectors;
    this.bindEvents();
  }

};

SmoothScroll.init();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
s.Link.click(function() {
  SmoothScroll.scroll();
});
```

To

```
s.Link.click(SmoothScroll.scroll);
```

Now `this` inside the `scroll` function will be the element

---

If the different contexts of `this` are confusing , you could pass the element as an argument of `scroll` instead

```
 bindEvents: function() {
   s.Link.click(function() {
     // "this" is element determined by jQuery 
     SmoothScroll.scroll(this);
   });
 },
 scroll: function(link) {
    // this === SmoothScroll
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == link.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == link.hostname && $(".classes .section").has(link).length == 0 ) {
      var target = $(link.hash);
  .....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Now it works. I just have a question.. why in this case I use scroll without (), but inside the init function I use bindevents() with the ()?

Comment: because you are passing the function as reference as opposed to passing an anonymous function that would get `this` as context for element

Comment: And what if I need to bind more functions inside bindEvents?

Comment: depends what you need to do. If they are event listeners would do same thing as click

Comment: @Matteo Then you should use [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)! Or pass the element as a parameter!

Comment: keep in mind that it is jQuery that is determining context of this within `scroll` in my answer based on what you asked for

Comment: Couldn't I instead name "this" in the scroll function in a different manner? In a way that I could refer it to my Link?

Comment: perhaps for less confusion about what `this` is....you should pass the element as an argument into `scroll` ....then replace all the `this` with the element argument